# Does CruiseControl support Maven3?

Tags: continuous-integration, maven-3, cruisecontrol

Im doing some research in order to find out what the best continuous integration server is. For that i would like to know (like the title says):

Does CruiseControl support Maven3?

At the main-page of CruiseControl i just found maven2.

Thanks in advance